Why does my topology book call the $T_1$ axiom Tikhonov?
Is this a historical term?
This seems to come in conflict with what I read about Tychonoff spaces (I guess, a misspelling), that seems to also (among others) imply $T_2$.
Is it safe to now call $T_1$ spaces Frechet? (As in, the community would universally know what I'm referring to without confusion).
Is my book outdated? (Ya Viro et al.)

Not sure why $T_1$ spaces would be so called, but regarding the misspelling, there is no universally-accepted translation from the Cyrillic script to Latin script. For example, as I understand it, the endings of "v" and "ff" are both acceptable Latin script translations of the Cyrillic letter Ve, which looks like a capital B.

@Theo Bendit: regarding the misspelling --- Indeed, see this Google-Books search.

Frechet is fine, but using the T_1 notation is probably most familiar.
